# Obtain rate as a function of position for a force $F=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^{2}$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, drag

I have trouble getting the speed as a function of position for a force of the form:

$$F=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^{2}$$

I had thought to use Newton's second law, so:

$$ma=m\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^{2}$$

Where $a$ is the acceleration and $v$ is the velocity.

Since v (x), using the chain rule:

$$ma=m\frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^{2}$$

Accordingly:

$$m\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}=-b\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)$$

However, I can not solve this equation. My questions are: Is it possible to solve this equation? I made an error in the procedure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you write $F = -b(\mathrm{d}x/\mathrm{d}t)^2$ as $F = -bv^2$ instead, Newton's second law becomes

$$m\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} = -bv^2$$

which should look a lot more manageable.